# how to sort products on custom attribute and then on sku in magento 2 category page

Tags: magento2, category-products, sorting

how to sort products on **custom attribute** (i.e. brands) first and then on sku in **magento 2** **category page**

For example

if 10 products have same brand then it should sort that 10 products on SKU

Comment: What happened when you add multiple sort? like Order By brands, sku?

Comment: Noting happen when i add $_productCollection = $block->getLoadedProductCollection()->setOrder('sku', 'asc'); in list.phtml